# JQuery TableSorter with Pager and LightWindow problem

Tags: jquery, tablesorter, lightwindow

I've a tablesorter with attached pager plugin on my page with links 'Details' in the one of the cell. Links have a class='lightwindow' and after clicking is rising up a LightWindow script with a window. So it work's vell on the First Page .. when i click Next Page on SortTable.Pager and clickin on my link 'Details' it's doesnt work correctly, it looks like my links lost their class='lightwindow'.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure what it is that is going on.  So the links have the class of lightwindow so as to trigger the lightwindow, obviously, but the pager on the table does not work any longer?